# How to increment a shared counter between parallel processes from the furrr package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, progress-bar, purrr, furrr

The example below parallelizes 64 `Sys.sleep(1)` instructions using the `furrr` package.

The package `progressr` is used to display the progression of the parallel execution.

This package allows to update some text details where I want to show the count of the number of terminated instructions.

But I do not know how to share a counter between the `furrr` process so with my 8-core cpu it shows `8/64` at max as you can see:

[image]

---

```
library(furrr)
library(progressr)

handlers("progress")

long_process <- function(items) {

  nb_of_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
  plan(multisession, workers = nb_of_cores)

  N <- length(items)
  p <- progressr::progressor(along = items)

  n <- 0

  item_process <- function(item) {
    n <<- n + 1
    p(paste(n, "/", N))
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }

  future_walk(items, item_process)
}

with_progress(long_process(1:64))
```

Comment: Sharing objects between parallel process is not possible without major(!) engineering, e.g. synchronization locks, mutexes, ... and if you'd try to go down that path, it's a painful experience and rarely worth your time.

Comment: The **progressr** package keeps track of the overall progress for you. In your example, it already reports on `8 / 64` - isn't that exactly the information you're interested in?

Comment: The report here 8/64 is wrong because it shows the counter of only one of the sub-process. Somehow progressr does the job since the progress bar and the percentage of progression are accurate. But I want to be able to show the absolute number and the percentage.

Comment: "The report here 8/64 is wrong because it shows the counter of only one of the sub-process." => I think you're missing something. **progressr** will definitely report an all iterations, i.e. 1/64, ..., 64/64.  You need to set up the format of your **progress** handler to show that. I'll post an answer with an example showing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example showing how to customize the **progress** package handler taken from https://progressr.futureverse.org/#further-configuration-of-progress-handlers:

```r
library(furrr)
library(progressr)

## Use the 'progress' package with custom format output for
## progress reporting, 
handlers(handler_progress(
  format = ":spin :current/:total [:bar] :percent"
))
  
## Parallelize on the local machine using all available cores
## Comment: Avoid putting this inside functions; leave it to
## the end-user to control this
plan(multisession)


long_process <- function(items) {
  p <- progressr::progressor(along = items)
  item_process <- function(item) {
    p()
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
  future_walk(items, item_process)
}

with_progress(long_process(1:64))
```

This gives a progress bar in the terminal that looks like:

```
/ 19/64 [============>------------------------------]  30%
```

Note that **progress** is superseded by the **cli** package. To achieve the same using the **cli** handler, use:

```r
handlers(handler_cli(
  type = "tasks",
  format = "{cli::pb_spin} {cli::pb_current}/{cli::pb_total} {cli::pb_bar} {cli::pb_percent}"
))
```

That will render like:

```
⠼ 19/64 ■■■■■■■■■                       30%
```

Comment: My original problem was to display the `current/total` ratio in the `detail` part of the `withProgressShiny` function which is updated when you call `p("3/64")`. I try to put it simply in a question but do you have a quick tip or do you prefer that I ask another question?

Comment: "My original problem was to display the current/total ratio in the detail part of the withProgressShiny": I see. So that's related to [`progressr::handler_shiny()`](https://progressr.futureverse.org/reference/handler_shiny.html), which is a light-weight adaptor to [`shiny::withProgress()`](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/latest/withprogress). Ideally, `shiny::withProgress()` would have built-in support for this. You could post to a feature request to <https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/progressr/issues> for adding some type of `format` argument support to `progressr::handler_shiny()`.